# countability of the subset of cartesian product of integers

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let us consider the set $X$ of the following infinite dimensional vectors:

$$
x = (x_{1}, x_{2}, \dots, x_{k}, 0, \dots,), 
$$
such that $x_{i} \in \mathbb{Z}$ and for any $x$ there exist $k < \infty$ such that $x_{j} = 0$ for all $j > k$.

The statement: $X$ is not countable.

Try:
I tried to show this using the fact that the set of all subsets of all integers is uncountable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement is wrong: The set is countable. Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/354592/620957) question. That question assumes natural numbers, but the argument is the same for integers (or any countable set).

Comment: awesome! I see now! yes, $X$ can be any countable set.